# Using NSManagedObjects from a NSArrayController in another thread

Tags: multithreading, cocoa, core-data

Can I savely modify a NSArrayControllers .selectedObjects from within another thread when the controller is bound to the main object context?
like:

```
   // Code in some thread
   for(NSMangedObject * aObject in _ArrayController.selectedObjects) {
       [aObject setValue:value forKey:key];
   }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Core Data isn't thread safe. You'll need a second `NSManagedObjectContext` (one for each thread).